# Modifing custom attributes of a loaded dll

Tags: c#, custom-attributes

Is there a way to modify a customAttribute of a loaded dll 
1) during runtime in c#
or
2) specifying an attribute under the `<Reference>... </Reference>` in .csproj?

Comment: AFAIK, no. What problem are you trying to solve?